# Wiremock (docker) - retrieved Zip response is a lot larger

Tags: docker, wiremock

In a CI/CD environment we first create a specific Wiremock Docker container via a Dockerfile:

```
FROM wiremock/wiremock:latest
COPY wiremock /home/wiremock
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh", "--global-response-templating", "--verbose"]
```

Yes, I noticed that in the examples of [this article](https://wiremock.org/docs/standalone/docker/) the --disable-gzip is mentioned. I guess, just as an example. Correct.

We copy some Zip files into the container.

The response headers contain:

- Content-Type=application/zip or application/octet-stream?
- Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=extract.zip
- Content-Length: 2094

The retrieved file has size 3644. It is not a valid Zip file. Why? How to get the real file as a response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works again! The main reason was that the example Dockerfile was not correct for this use case!

Dockerfile:

```
FROM wiremock/wiremock
COPY stubs /home/wiremock
```

The zip file is put in stubs/__files as sample-zip.zip.

The stubs/mappings/mappingzip.json contains:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/fileserver/samplezip"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "sample-zip.zip",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/zip",
      "Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=\"file.zip\""
    }
  }
}
```

Another variant is in stubs/mappings/mappingzip2.json:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/fileserver/samplezip2"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "sample-zip.zip",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
      "Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=\"file2.zip\""
    }
  }
}
```

The created docker image is put in the Docker hub.

The standard K8s deployment file is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wiremockdemo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wiremockdemo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wiremockdemo
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: wiremockdemo
          image: yourdockerhubaccount/wiremockdemo:development
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

The Service file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wiremockdemo
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 9200
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: wiremockdemo
  type: LoadBalancer
```

These commands launched the wiremock server as a Kubernetes service:

- kubectl apply -f wiremockdemo-deployment.yaml
- kubectl apply -f wiremockdemo-service.yaml

Browse results:

- http://localhost:9200/__admin/mappings
- http://localhost:9200/__admin/files
- http://localhost:9200/fileserver/samplepdf
- http://localhost:9200/fileserver/samplezip1
- http://localhost:9200/fileserver/samplezip2